# When is a stack a sheaf?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes, algebraic-stacks

On big etale site we have the slogan

> *"Schemes are sheaves, sheaves are stacks"*

Now we know there are sheaves which are not schemes, in fact a sheaf is a scheme iff it is representable as a functor.

> When is a stack a sheaf?

> What is an example of a stack which is not a sheaf?

Comment: A slogan-y answer might be, a stack is a sheaf iff its sections are discrete. Is that the kind of answer you are looking for?

Comment: I'm not sure what sort of answer you are looking for here, and slightly worry that you might need to read more about the basic definitions. That said, a stack is a sheaf when (essentially by definition) its fiber categories are discrete groupoids (i.e. equivalent to sets). A slightly non-trivial reformulation of this is that the map $\mathcal{I}_X\to X$ is an equivalence, where $\mathcal{I}_X$ is the inertia stack. An example of a stack which is not a sheaf is any stack where the fibers have non-trivial automorphisms -- for exmaple $[\ast/G]$.